# get_googlemaps returning map with warped longitude/latitude in R?

Tags: r, ggmap

I'm trying to retrieve a tile of Downtown Los Angeles from Google Maps using `ggmap` and `ggplot2`, specifically the function `get_googlemaps`, and then I want to overlay a shapefile over it displaying the boundary of Downtown Los Angeles. (The shapefile is from the LA Times, [here](http://boundaries.latimes.com/set/la-county-neighborhoods-current/)) I clipped the shapefile to only show DTLA by doing this to retain the attributes:

```
downtown <- readOGR(".","neighborhoods.shp")
downtown@data$id <- rownames(downtown@data)
downtown.points <- fortify(downtown,region="id")
downtown.df <- join(downtown.points,downtown@data,by="id")`
```

I then clipped out everything that wasn't DTLA by subsetting

`downtown.df <- downtown.df[downtown$slug="downtown",]`

`downtown.df` plots fine with

`ggplot(downtown.df, aes(x=long,y=lat)) + geom_polygon(fill=NA, color="black") + coord_fixed()`.

Then I go to get the DTLA map using ggmap.

```
dtlamap <- get_googlemap(location = c(lon=-118.250347,lat=34.044899), 
    zoom=14,
    maptype="roadmap",
    style="element:labels|visibility:off|
    style=feature:administrative.land_parcel|
    visibility:off|style=feature:administrative.neighborhood
    |visibility:off")
ggmap(dtlamap)
```

The map that appears is correct, but the latitude and longitude are warped. The latitude range is 29.74 to 29.78 and the longitude range is -95.39 to -95.34. So when I try to plot `downtown.df` on top of it, it doesn't display because the coordinates are off.

The polygon for the DTLA shp file is in the WDS84 system and I assume the Google Maps is too, or it wouldn't have pulled up the correct map...?

I looked at this google group answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/ggplot2/ABffHL3WTpY) but I can't get the solution to work for me using `get_googlemap`.

Comment: Where does `join` come from? Please try and include all packages that you are using in your code with `library(...)`.  Also this line `downtown.df <- downtown.df[downtown$slug="downtown",]` is invalid because you probaly meant to use `==` instead of `=` - please try and make a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing, you can't use `downtown.df[downtown$slug="downtown",]` because `dim(downtown)` != `dim(downtown.df)`. You need to select before `fortify`. Also, shapefile came in NAD 83, so you need to reproject it:

```
downtown <- spTransform(downtown, '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs ')
downtown@data$id <- rownames(downtown@data)
downtown <- downtown[downtown$slug == 'downtown',]
downtown.points <- fortify(downtown,region="id")
downtown.df <- join(downtown.points,downtown@data,by="id")
```

Second, `get_googlemap` function uses `center` argument, not `location` (this one is for `get_map` function) and third, `ggmap` doesn't work fine when the polygon is bigger than extent, so use `zoom = 13` (or you can cut polygon with extent of `zoom = 14`):

```
dtlamap <- get_googlemap(center = c(lon=-118.250347,lat=34.044899), 
                         zoom=13,
                         maptype="roadmap",
                         style="element:labels|visibility:off|
                         style=feature:administrative.land_parcel|
                         visibility:off|style=feature:administrative.neighborhood
                         |visibility:off")

ggmap(dtlamap) + geom_polygon(data = downtown.df, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This really helped explain what I was doing incorrectly. I appreciate the time you took to answer this. :)